# How to plot histograms from rows in data file gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, histogram

t.dat file looks like this:

```
              260.37
              260.04
              261.53
              261.32
              260.19
              260.49
              260.43
              260.59
              260.26
              260.68
              260.28
              259.93
              260.82
              259.50
              260.29
              260.52
              260.30
              259.91
              262.24
              260.58
              260.74
              260.22
              261.66
              260.31
              260.99
              259.79
              260.90
              259.88
              260.19
              261.50
              259.32
              260.79
              259.94
              260.35
              260.03
              260.07
              261.86
              261.09
              260.60
              260.15
               75.17
               75.16
               75.33
               75.31
               75.34
               75.04
               75.49
               75.25
               75.27
               75.32
               75.10
               75.75
               75.58
               74.86
               75.19
               75.44
               75.29
               75.31
               75.55
               75.91
               75.39
               75.65
               75.85
               75.67
               75.62
               74.87
               75.64
               75.69
               75.13
               77.76
               75.31
               74.87
               75.75
               75.27
               75.61
               74.84
               75.72
               75.40
               74.96
               75.33
               67.20
               67.26
               68.15
               68.67
               68.88
               67.56
               67.71
               66.87
               68.74
               67.32
               66.92
               69.62
               67.29
               66.87
               68.33
               67.73
               68.66
               68.75
               67.00
               67.22
               66.93
               68.81
               67.29
               67.18
               67.33
               67.91
               70.34
               67.15
               68.37
               69.60
               69.74
               69.62
               67.33
               66.79
               67.90
               67.39
               69.88
               68.48
               68.96
               67.36
               47.82
               47.54
               47.74
               47.95
               47.65
               47.71
               47.64
               47.71
               47.47
               48.19
               47.82
               48.06
               47.88
               48.22
               48.31
               47.58
               47.41
               47.85
               47.71
               47.93
               48.34
               47.95
               48.70
               47.58
               47.86
               47.96
               47.80
               48.00
               47.51
               47.56
               47.50
               47.52
               47.47
               47.76
               47.53
               48.27
               47.26
               47.79
               47.67
               47.57
```

The objective is to print 4 series of histograms, each one separated with spaces, one for each group of every 40 lines. So that histogram group 1 plots data from lines 1:40, second group plots the data from lines 41:80, and so on.
So far I've managed to print the first group of histograms separately:

```
set boxwidth 0.9 relative
set style data histograms
set style fill solid 1.0 border -1
set xtics ("1" 20, "4" 60, "8" 100, "16" 140)
plot 't.dat' using 1 with boxes ls 6 axes x1y1
```

and print the four groups concatenated:

```
plot 't.dat' using 1 every ::0::39 with boxes ls 6 axes x1y1
```

How do I do to plot the other groups in the same plot?

Comment: I rolled back the question to its original version because you posted the update as new question. This keeps this question here much clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, that `set style data histograms` is ignored, because you overwrite it with the `with boxes`, and `boxes` and `histograms` are different ways to plot bar charts from the view point of grouping and arranging the data.

If you can plot the first group with

```
plot "t.dat" using 0:1 every ::0::39 with boxes
```

then you can plot the second group with

```
plot "t.dat" using 0:1 every ::40::79 with boxes
```

(`using 1`,  like you used is implicitely converted to `using 0:1` by gnuplot).
These two plots would overlap because the zeroth column, i.e. the number of the current row only counts the rows which are available after applying the `every` filter, so in both cases the x-values go from `0` to `39`. To have both plotted beneath each other you must add `40` to the second plot (or maybe `41` to have a small gap between the two:

```
plot "t.dat" using 0:1 every ::0::39 with boxes,\
     "" using ($0 + 41):1 every ::40::79 with boxes
```

Now, to plot all four groups you can either expand this plot command to hold also the other two groups, or you iterate over them with

```
set boxwidth 0.7 relative
set style fill solid 1.0 noborder
set xtics ("1" 19.5, "4" 60.5, "8" 101.5, "16" 142.5)
unset key 
plot for [i=1:4] 't.dat' using ($0+(i-1)*41):1 every ::((i-1)*40)::(i*40-1) with boxes lt i
```

[image]